# java lock gets locked by another thread when it's locked

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I'm all out of ideas on why this happens. What I'm trying to do is to have one thread do some work, then another thread process the results of that work and when it's finished the first thread goes back into action. So I'm giving both threads a reference to a single ReentrantLock. The first thread locks it, does its work, then releases it and sleeps for a few milliseconds to let the other thread acquire the lock and do its work and then the process continues.

The problem is that it appears that the lock gets locked by the second thread **while it's still locked by the first**. I can't figure out why. I wrote a simple class to try and recreate the scenario but there everything goes as expected. I've also looked into my code and I'm not releasing the locks anywhere unexpected. I've also tried replacing the lock with a `new Semaphore(1)` and the same thing happens.

Here are the relevant lines form the log:

```
12204 [Thread-2] DEBUG AggregatedEventProducerThread:37 - Attempting to acquire lock java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@43e36bfa[Unlocked]. Timestamp 1453223023635
12204 [Thread-2] DEBUG AggregatedEventProducerThread:39 - Lock acquired at 1453223023636. java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@43e36bfa[Locked by thread Thread-2]
12564 [Thread-5] DEBUG CoordinatorState:151 - Attempting to acquire lock java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@43e36bfa[Locked by thread Thread-2]. Timestamp 1453223023995
13454 [Thread-5] DEBUG CoordinatorState:154 - Lock java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@43e36bfa[Locked by thread Thread-5] acquired at 1453223024886.
23915 [Thread-5] DEBUG CoordinatorState:161 - Lock java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@43e36bfa[Unlocked] released at 1453223035346.
28458 [Thread-2] DEBUG AggregatedEventProducerThread:45 - Lock released at 1453223039890. java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@43e36bfa[Unlocked]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post some code exemplifying your issue.

Comment: Is it possible you are calling unlock() too many times or calling it from the AggregatedEventProducerThread before it acquires the lock? I would try calling tryLock() and getHoldCount() in a few places around the lock (both before and after) and logging those results, then analyzing the log to see if they are what you expect.

Comment: Rule #1, don't use `sleep()` to synchronize threads.  Using `sleep()` calls, you can make it very likely that your threads will run in the right order, but you can never make it absolutely guaranteed that they will run in the right order.  (I like to remind my co-workers, you can use sleep to make tests pass, but not to make the code work right in the customer's environment.)  The longer your threads sleep, the more likely that your program will do the right thing, but the more time it will waste sleeping.

Comment: Rule #2:  Don't tie threads to the work that they do.  The best way to do task A followed by task B followed by task C is to do all of those tasks in a _single thread_.  You should try to structure your program such that when there's a task to be performed, it does not matter which thread performs the task.

Comment: #3 Don't try to use lock objects (or Semaphores) to control the order of things.  Most lock implementations provide no guarantee as to the order in which the threads will acquire the lock when two or more try to acquire it at the same time.  If you think you need different threads to perform tasks in a particular order, maybe you could re-structure your code so that the tasks are _objects_ that go into a queue.  Queues preserve order.

Comment: It is possible that the logs are in the wrong order - `System.out.println` is synchronized, so it's possible that the first thread unlocks the lock, and second does its work before the first is able to print to the console. Try using an `AtomicInteger` that you increment after locking, print its value and decrement before unlock; I don't think it's possible for multiple threads to acquire the same lock at the same time.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie There are timestamps at the end of each log line showing when the action occurred.

Comment: You didn't post the code, so I have no idea if they are created in the correct place. Anyway, I'd try the `AtomicInteger` to count the threads first and if it prints `2`, something is definitely wrong.